# Do we care about singularities on the path when using the Residue theorem? (And other theorems in complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Take for example the Residue theorem, if we want to calculate a line integral around the unit circle say and the function isn't defined at some points on the unit circle say $f(z)=1/(z-1)$ then if we wanted to calculate $\int f(z) dz$  around the unit circle via the residue theorem would we have to factor in the residue at $1$ or would it simply be $2\pi i\cdot0=0$? I ask the question also more generally for Cauchy's integral formula as well do we actually care if the function is defined (and holomorphic ) on the path or just it's interior?

Thanks.

Comment: The integral $\int_C f(z) dz$ is not even defined when $f$ is not defined on the whole curve $C$. So, it doesn't make sense to even talk about the integral of $1/(z-1)$ around the unit circle, as it isn't defined there.

Comment: @ Daniel : yes of course singularities on the contour are a problem, for example $\int_{|z| = 0.999} \frac{dz}{z-1} = 0$ while$\int_{|z| = 1.001} \frac{dz}{z-1} = 2 i \pi$, hence you can't find any acceptable definition for a contour integral with singularities on the contour (there is still the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value but it is not a full satisfactory solution)

Comment: and why don't you simply prove the Cauchy integral formula ? you'll see immediately why we ask the contour to be contained on a simply connected open-set where the function is holomorphic (hence the function is holomorphic on the contour and on its interior and on its exterior neighborhood)